# How to correlate CPU benchmarks to overall computer performance?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

I am in the market for a new PC, and I know I can look up the CPU model name to see which one performs better in a benchmark test.

However, how do I translate this into PC performance?  What sort of benchmark performance should one look for if they want:

1. browsing and light office work
2. fast, high performance office work
3. to run engineering applications (matlab, solidworks)
4. gaming

Comment: You mention different scenarios that do not necessarily translate into a simple CPU performance situation....there are a number of parameters to consider here, graphics, disk, display, memory....

Comment: If you're worried about performance, then buy the fastest of everything that you can afford.

Comment: Whats with all these questions, this is the third question, of this type I have read.

Comment: Instead of CPU benchmarks, look for PC benchmarks, that try hard to do their measurements on real-world types of tasks.  If you compare system-wide benchmark results on two computers that differ only in the processor, you find the contribution of CPU to those tasks.

Answer (score 2):

How to correlate CPU benchmarks to overall computer performance?

The answer is simple:  *You can't*.

A computer's CPU is only one factor of *many* when it comes to computer performance.  RAM size and speed, hard disk speed, motherboard, etc, etc... all plays important roles in a computer's speed.  Each one helping or hindering in some aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at CPUs, there are 3 main parts to take a note of : Clock Speed (2.5 GHz, 3.7 GHz etc.), cores (quad-core, dual-core, octa-core, hexa-core),and threads. For example, a quad-core CPU with a clock-speed of 3.9 GHz may not be as good as a 10-core CPU at 3.2 GHz. This is becuase the 10-core CPU may have more threads and more processing cores. The more processing cores and threads, the more programs you can have processing in the background (better multi-tasking).

In my opinion, you should go for an AMD FX CPU. Some are hexa-core and have about 4-6 threads. They also cost about $100-$200 USD.